# Which is the better Push notification system to use with Nativescript?

Tags: push-notification, nativescript

I'm a Xamarin dev, but I'm exploring Nativescript.
So I've a question.
Which is the better Push notification system to use with Nativescript? 
I like to use Visual Studio App Center. Is't nativescript compatible?
Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Nativescript community advises to use https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase for push notifications. You can use Visual Studio App Center for nativescript cloud builds.

Comment: I recommend the linked plugin too. I used it within 3 Apss and it is one of the few things at nativescript that work almost without any issues.

Comment: Uhm, but there is not support for Visual Studio App Center Push Notification.

Answer (score 1):

Of course Firebase will be my recommendation too as it's one single plugin for most common requirements that includes Push Notification.

But if you have plans for using other third parties, there are plugins available for Urban Airship, Azure etc., It's also possible to manage your own backend for sending Push Notification.

Comment: I like Visual Studio App Center. Which is for Azure?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using nativescript worker

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/multithreading-model

and nativescript-local-notifications plugin

in your ./worker/sendpush.js

```
require('globals');
var notification = require("nativescript-local-notifications");

onmessage =  function(msg){

if(msg.data.success == true)
{
    notification.schedule([{
    id : 1,
    title: 'New message',
    badge : 1,
    body: data.msg,
    smallIcon : 'res://icon'
    ]).then(function() {
       console.log("Notification scheduled");
    },function(error) {
       console.log("scheduling error: " + error);
    })        
}
```

in your main-page.js

```
var getloc = new Worker("./workers/get-location");
getloc.postMessage({msg : "blabla", success : true});
```